# Присваивание массиву процедуры

Tags: java

Подскажите, как присвоить массиву процедуру и можно ли такое делать и как?

```
fac(double l){..}
...
string[] mas = fac(n); // не работает
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] mirtrudmaj(double l){..}
...
String[] mas = mirtrudmaj(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

В Java нельзя.